# Minecraft 1.7.10 Coremod Modifications to InventoryPlayer

Tags: java, minecraft

I wrote a simple coremod change to the hasItem method of the InventoryPlayer class. It's not that hard, but the problem is that Coremod's change to this class seems to be queued up right before the game. (That doesn't seem to work?) I wrote a simple event test and it worked out the same way. Then I wrote a Transformer to rewrite the getCommandSender function in the EntityPlayer class, and it worked. And from the log to see changes in   Launching wrapped minecraft {net. Minecraft. Client. The main}  , started after the main, but the change of InventoryPlayer ranked before entering the archive. Source code for https://github.com/HowXuVSCode/Core. I evaluated the replacement hasItem to always return false, but it returned true as soon as I entered the game...

I checked Google but there's nothing to look at. And my English was poor, so it was difficult to find useful documents.Maybe I need some practical documentation, or maybe you can help me point out my silly mistakes. Thank you very much for your help in your busy schedule. I wish you a happy life!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.